# Do Arduino Boards contain enough processing power for 4 DOF Robotic Arm

Tags: arduino, robotic-arm

I am starting to work with 4 DOF Robotic Arm project.it has the following specs:

1- the speed of the tip of the end-effector is constant and adjustable.

2- the robot is controlled via joysticks which determine the direction of movement of the end-effector.

3- also the orientation of the end-effector is controlled.

to implement these specs I need a processor that can handle forward kinematics, inverse kinematics, trajectory related calculations in addition to reading from sensors and camera.

can Arduino Handle all that?

what are alternatives available?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mohammed Abdulmonem, but I'm afraid that questions like this are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that a single arduino board will be able to handle all that.

Maybe start out with implementing controllers on your arduino? And let your computer handle the kinematics, camera and so on? Then you will also learn about communication between your computer and a Arduino board.

Another alternative may be a Raspberry PI, but I don't know about the computational power in that one. I think your biggest limitation is the camera, but I may be wrong.

Comment: A Pi would have more than enough power to do it, as would an Arduino. The question actually should be "Will the input=>output latency be low enough to be tolerable?" With an Arduino you will likely face considerable latency with a mere 30MHz at the high end of speeds. But with a Pi it might be very acceptable since even the lowest one currently production (the Pi0) has a clock speed of 1GHz.

Comment: Of course, you could just do what many robot manufacturers do and heavily divide the workload between many smaller, weaker boards with one serving as a serial communications manager (or you could try the headache of a headless architecture).